# Build a voice assistant to open the application with a path in the curly bracket

Tags: python, voice-recognition

I wondered if I could add a lot of paths to open the application, but my code only opens the calculator when I ask to open chrome. It shows me like this `The file /System/Applications/Google Chrome.app does not exist.` Suppose you want to fix my code to be better. I am on a mac, by the way. Thank you.

my code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS
import playsound
import os
import subprocess as sp
import random

def take_command():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
        print('listening...')
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            text = r.recognize_google(audio)
            text = text.lower()
            print(f"user: {text}")  # print user app said
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            speak('Sorry, I did not get that')
            text = None
        except sr.RequestError:
            speak('Request error')
            text = None
        return text


def speak(audio_string):
    tts = gTTS(text=audio_string, lang='en-uk', slow=False)  # text to speech(voice)
    recognizer = random.randint(1, 20000000)
    audio_file = 'audio' + str(recognizer) + '.mp3'
    tts.save(audio_file)  # save as mp3
    print('\33[1m' f"computer: {audio_string}")  # print what app said
    playsound.playsound(audio_file)  # play the audio file
    os.remove(audio_file)  # remove audio file


paths = {
    "chrome": ['open', '/System/Applications/Google Chrome.app'],
    "excel": ['open', '/System/Applications/Microsoft Excel.app'],
    "calculator": ['open', '/System/Applications/Calculator.app'],
}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        query = take_command()

        if str(query) in paths:
            app = paths.get(query)
            sp.call(app)

        elif 'bye' in str(query):
            exit()
        
        else:
            speak('Please repeat the command.')
```

terminal:

```
listening...
user: chrome
The file /System/Applications/Google Chrome.app does not exist.
listening...
user: calculator
listening...
user: bye
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the Chrome Path as:

```
paths = {
    "chrome": ['open', '/Applications/Google Chrome.app'],
    "excel": ['open', '/System/Applications/Microsoft Excel.app'],
    "calculator": ['open', '/System/Applications/Calculator.app'],
}
```

This is the default chrome install location.